# Settings.Secure WIFI_ON Android Application crash

Tags: android, crash, wifi, settings.settings

I'm trying to write a simple app, that will change Android(my ver is 2.3.3) settings, but I have some problems. My API level is 10, so I use System.Secure, because Settings.System are deprecated and Settings.Global are in newer APIs.

When I use this code, app crashes :( :

```
public class OnOff extends Activity {
TextView msg;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
//buttonLED = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON, 1);
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON, 0);
        }
    }
});
}
}
```

Of course I use permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

I also tried this code with android:onClick="toggle" but it doesn't work too :/

```
public class OnOff extends Activity {
TextView msg;
private ToggleButton buttonLED;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void toggle(View v){
if(buttonLED.isChecked()){
    Toast.makeText(OnOff.this, "Setting ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON, 1);
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(OnOff.this, "Setting OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON, 0);

}
}
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to make it work?

Comment: Settings.Secure.WIFI_ON is only defined in API 17 (Jelly Bean), for lower API levels you should use System.Secure.WIFI_ON, however as mentioned in the answer, you can't write secure settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the values of secure table, unless your app is bundled with the system ([RTM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)):

> Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read **but are not allowed to write**. These are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values, **not modified directly by applications**.

Comment: Ok, so I need to find another way :/